# How to import a project from Xcode to QtCreator

Tags: xcode, user-interface, qt-creator

What I am trying to do is to create a graphic user interface for a program which I coded in Xcode, so my question is, how can I import the file in QtCreator and create a guy.
I've tried New Project->Import->Import existing project but I can not build it I get

> "No rule to target 'all'. Stop."

However when i create a new qt empty project I am able to build and run it, cand somebody help me please? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XCode keeps project settings in special format (property list, deprecated OpenSTEP variant), which QtCreator cannot read. Fortunately, XCode provides utility 'xcodebuild', it can build *.xcodeproj correctly.

1. Go to Project Settings (5th mode, hotkey: Ctrl+5).
2. Find Build Steps section and disable "Make" step
3. Add new step "Custom Process Step" and call xcodebuild with working directory "%{sourceDir}"

   [image]